# Leetcode Minimum Path Sum

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I am working on an question called minimum path sum. I have made my logic and find it to be true but I am getting Runtime Error in the code. I have searched properly but can't find any mistake. Here is the code:-

```
  class Solution {
public:
    int minPathSum(vector<vector<int>>& grid) {
       int colsize=grid.size();
        int rowsize=grid[0].size();
       for(int i=1;i<rowsize;i++)
       {
           grid[0][i]+=grid[0][i-1];
       }
       for(int i=1;i<colsize;i++)
       {
           grid[i][0]+=grid[i-1][0];
       }

        for(int i=1;i<rowsize;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<colsize;j++)
            {
                grid[i][j]+=min(grid[i-1][j],grid[i][j-1]);
            }
        }
        return grid[rowsize-1][colsize-1];
       
        
    }
};
```

and the link to the question
https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-path-sum/

For the test Case:-

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

It is giving runtime error.

Comment: you changed your code completely. Which version results in a runtime error? The original or this one? or both?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I have just made some changes for code readibility and also corrected the rowsize and colsize error. Still the same error during submission.

Comment: you fixed the error that was pointed out in the answer. you shouldnt change your question to ask for something else after you recieved an answer. Please do not fix errors in your question. Fixed code is for answers

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 got it

Comment: Why haven't you debugged your code, given that you have a test case that gives the error? Compile [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ecaf8a9f2aa9115) locally, and then you can debug it locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you accidentally swapped `colsize` and `rowsize` in the latter half of your question:

```
        for(int i=1;i<rowsize;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<colsize;j++)
            {
                grid[i][j]+=min(grid[i-1][j],grid[i][j-1]);
            }
        }
        return grid[rowsize-1][colsize-1];
```

It should be:

```
        for(int i=1;i<colsize;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<rowsize;j++)
            {
                grid[i][j]+=min(grid[i-1][j],grid[i][j-1]);
            }
        }
        return grid[colsize-1][rowsize-1];
```

Because `colsize` is used as the limit for the first index and `rowsize` is used as the limit for the second index.

Comment: This is why `n` and `m` are terrible names

Comment: @Woodford Corrected

Comment: @VaibhavAngi Updated